# Pulling data out of a text field

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have a notetext field that will have 2 fields in it: `price` and `desc`

The price is never the same amount of characters and is in text format
Example:  (*51445 text description*) or (*9801 text description*)

How do I set it up to pull the amount out and then have it formatted with 2 decimals?

I have tried: `LEFT(note_text,CHARINDEX(' ', note_text) - 1) AS Incoming_Cust_Prc` but this isn't working. I am getting an error

> ORA-00904 LEFT invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that the DBMS is Oracle rather than SQL Server in which there are functions such as `LEFT()` and `CHARINDEX()`. Thus, use Oracle functions as

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(note_text,1,INSTR(note_text,' ')), 'fm999G999D00') AS Incoming_Cust_Prc,
       SUBSTR(note_text,INSTR(note_text,' ')+1,LENGTH(note_text)) AS Incoming_Cust_Desc
  FROM t
```

in order to get two seperate columns `price` and `description`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8312cdec4053714febe16b2640a0a3cf)</kbd>